# stackpanel visibility based on label content not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a stack panel that I want to make visible based on a label's content. Just not sure why it isnt working for me. What's highlighted in bold is what I want to hide. Any suggestion?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Label Nane="lblCarrier" Content="{Binding Path=Carrier}" />
**<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=lblCarrier}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <Label x:Name="lblCarrierGrade" Content="Grade Carrier:" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCarrierGrade1" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCarrierGrade2" />
</StackPanel>**
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be that the `Content` is null rather than `String.Empty`.

You could try using [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=lblCarrier,TargetNullValue=''}" Value="">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The "TargetNullValue=''" is what made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a converter? Add a class file to you project like this:

```
class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your `Window` definition add this:

```
xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:[YourProjectName]"
```

Then somewhere in the resources add this

```
<myNamespace:VisibilityConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

Now you can use it:

```
 <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=lblCarrier,
                                Converter = {StaticResources myConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate it but I just wanted something simple and fast without having to do more.

Comment: OK. I would prefer that answer. :-)